# Cannot implicitly convert type 'void' to 'Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid.EventSubscriptionResource'

Tags: c#, azure-eventgrid

I am developing an Azure Eventgrid Subscription API provider solution using .NET and Azure Resource Manager.

When I want to retrieve an event subscription by calling the `GetEventSubscriptionAsync` method from the `eventGridClient` object (defined in `AzureEventGridClient.cs`) asynchronously, I get the following error:

[image: Error Message]

In my original client code (in `AzureEventGridClient.cs`), `GetEventSubscriptionAsync` is defined as:

```
     public async Task GetEventSubscriptionAsync(string eventSubscriptionName)
        {
            EventSubscriptionResource eventSubscription = this.collection.Get(eventSubscriptionName);

            EventSubscriptionResource result = await eventSubscription.GetAsync();
        }
```

I tried to delete `"return"` in front `"wait this.eventGridClient.GetEventSubscriptionAsync(eventSubscriptionName);"`, expecting for the error to go away because GetEventSubscriptionAsync is not supposed to return anything. Instead of the error going away, a new error appeared:

[image: The Error]

Answer (score 0):

the way how you wrote - it will not return anything...
for void - try to make as task

```
public async Task GetEventSubscriptionAsync(string eventSubscriptionName)
{
    await Task.Run(() => {
            EventSubscriptionResource eventSubscription = this.collection.Get(eventSubscriptionName);
            EventSubscriptionResource result = await eventSubscription.GetAsync();
    });
}

public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Azure.Response<Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid.EventSubscriptionResource>> GetEventSubscriptionAsync (this Azure.ResourceManager.ArmClient client, Azure.Core.ResourceIdentifier scope, string eventSubscriptionName, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);
```

but in microsoft documentation it looks like returns
Task<Azure.Response<Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid.EventSubscriptionResource>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.eventgrid.eventgridextensions.geteventsubscriptionasync?view=azure-dotnet

try to change return object from Task to

```
public async 
Task<Azure.Response<Azure.ResourceManager.EventGrid.EventSubscriptionResource> GetEventSubscriptionAsync(string eventSubscriptionName){
// put code here
}
```